# GIT on Solaris 10: Version 'SUNW_1.2' not found because of .profile settings

Tags: git, bash, unix, installation, solaris

We have installed GIT package on our Unix Server(Solaris 10). Post installation we have been receiving errors while running GIT command.

```
acdbad1@dipva01z:/home/acdbad1> git
```

> ```
> ld.so.1: git: fatal: libz.so.1: version 'SUNW_1.2' not found (required by file /opt/git/bin/git)
> ld.so.1: git: fatal: libz.so.1: open failed: No such file or directory
> Killed
> ```

We have gone back to unix support, but could not get satisfactory response. they have been telling that my `.profile` have some settings which is not letting it through.

We have renamed our `.profile` file and tried it, and we are able to run the git command. But our `.profile` have a lot of settings which we do not want to avoid.

So, Can someone advise us the way we can run git on the server without ignoring `.profile` file?

Will be able to provide more details if required.

Regards,
Lakshman

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any any lines changing the behaviour of using the libraries in your profile like LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? Without the .profile it's hard to say, what you need to remove in order to enable an successful start.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Below are the paths we are exporting 

LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32=/app/localapps/oracle/oracle64/lib32:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/opt/csw/lib/sparcv9
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}${LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32}:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH


PATH=/app/localapps/pcre/bin:/app/localapps/apr/bin:/usr/perl5/5.8.4/bin:/app/localapps/java/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sfw/lib:/usr/dt/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/s
bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/ucb:/etc:/app/localapps/oracle/oracle64/bin:/home/acdbad1/bin:/app/localapps/oracle/oracle64/lib32:${GIT_HOME}:.
export PATH

Comment: what is reported by ldd git ?

Comment: @Lakshman *LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32=/app/localapps/oracle/oracle64/lib32:/usr‌​/lib:/usr/local/lib:‌​/lib:/opt/csw/lib/sp‌​arcv9*?!?!?  Do you **really** have `/opt/csw/lib/sp‌​arcv9` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32`?  The `sparcv9` directory is for **64-bit** libraries.  Putting it in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable for **32-bit** libraries (hence the "_32" suffix...) is going to break things and break things badly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle .. I tried removing the path u mentioned from _32 variable and tried to run .profile file again but still finding the same error when running git command.

Looks like below now:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32=/app/localapps/oracle/oracle64/lib32:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}${LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32}:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @c0t0d0s0 .. 

acdbad1@dipva01z:/home/acdbad1> ldd git
ldd: git: cannot open file: No such file or directory

Comment: @c0t0d0s0

acdbad1@dipva01z:/app/ac_data/workdir> ldd /opt/git/bin/git
libz.so.1 =>     /app/ac/lib/libz.so.1
libz.so.1 (SUNW_1.2) =>  (version not found)
libsocket.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
libnsl.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
libresolv.so.2 =>        /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 =>    /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
libmp.so.2 =>    /usr/lib/libmp.so.2
libmd.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libmd.so.1
libscf.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libscf.so.1
libdoor.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libdoor.so.1

Contd..

Comment: libuutil.so.1 =>         /usr/lib/libuutil.so.1
libgen.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libgen.so.1
libm.so.2 =>     /usr/lib/libm.so.2
/lib/libm/libm_hwcap1.so.2
/platform/sun4v/lib/libc_psr.so.1
/platform/sun4v/lib/libmd_psr.so.1

Comment: I assume you have downloaded your git from opencsw, did you installed all dependencies as well? Especially the libz package ?